# how to handle consumer recovery by offset with shopify sarama

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, sarama

I've read that kafka provides a consumer client library that allows recovery by saving the last offset read in zookeeper (not 100% sure about where it's stored).

Is it possible to do the same with Sarama consumers?

Let's say that I'm reading until offset 550, my consumer crashes for 5 min, we are now at offset 700 but I want to resume consuming from offset 550.

Is that possible without having to save the state by myself?
I would assume it does but I don't understand how.

I've found `sarama.OffsetNewest/Oldest`but that's not what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka consumers used to store offsets in Zookeeper but now they store them directly in Kafka. See the [Consumer section](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#theconsumer) in the Kafka docs.

Sarama handles that very well and Sarama consumers will commit (store) offsets in Kafka by default.

Have a look at the Sarama [Consumer example](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/examples/consumergroup/main.go). Initially this example starts at the end of the topic but upon restarting, it will restart from its last position.

Comment: awesome, thank you for pointing out the part of doc explaining it.